# How to sort multi-indexed rows

Tags: pandas

If `df` is a Pandas dataframe with a 5-level multi-index on the rows, is there a less stupid way to achieve the ordering produced by this:

```
(df.sortlevel(3, sort_remaining=False)
   .sortlevel(2, sort_remaining=False)
   .sortlevel(0, sort_remaining=False)
   .sortlevel(1, sort_remaining=False)
   .sortlevel(4, sort_remaining=False))
```

?

NB: all of the following produce orderings different from that produced by the expression above:

```
df.sortlevel([4, 1, 0, 2, 3], sort_remaining=False)
df.sortlevel([4, 1, 0, 2, 3], sort_remaining=True)
df.sortlevel([3, 2, 0, 1, 4], sort_remaining=False)
df.sortlevel([3, 2, 0, 1, 4], sort_remaining=True)
```

Comment: @pansen: no, I checked; I've updated my post to make this clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes!  Don't use `sortlevel`.  Use `sort_index` with `level=[4, 1, 0, 2, 3]`

Consider the dataframe `df`

```
from string import ascii_uppercase
import pandas as pd

f = lambda n: np.random.choice(list(ascii_uppercase), n, False)
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([f(2) for _ in range(5)])
df = pd.Series(range(32), mux, name='One').to_frame()
print(df)

           One
T B W G U    0
        P    1
      M U    2
        P    3
    G G U    4
        P    5
      M U    6
        P    7
  V W G U    8
        P    9
      M U   10
        P   11
    G G U   12
        P   13
      M U   14
        P   15
R B W G U   16
        P   17
      M U   18
        P   19
    G G U   20
        P   21
      M U   22
        P   23
  V W G U   24
        P   25
      M U   26
        P   27
    G G U   28
        P   29
      M U   30
        P   31
```

Then sort

```
df.sort_index(level=[4, 1, 0, 2, 3])

           One
R B G G P   21
  V G G P   29
  B G M P   23
  V G M P   31
  B W G P   17
  V W G P   25
  B W M P   19
  V W M P   27
T B G G P    5
  V G G P   13
  B G M P    7
  V G M P   15
  B W G P    1
  V W G P    9
  B W M P    3
  V W M P   11
R B G G U   20
  V G G U   28
  B G M U   22
  V G M U   30
  B W G U   16
  V W G U   24
  B W M U   18
  V W M U   26
T B G G U    4
  V G G U   12
  B G M U    6
  V G M U   14
  B W G U    0
  V W G U    8
  B W M U    2
  V W M U   10
```

Since you sorted all levels, there is no need for `sort_remaining=False`